# How does one use enscripten installed on MacOS using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, emscripten

So I have installed the prerequisites for emscripten on a Mac (m1 mac silicon)
Then, from a shell done "brew install emscripten"  The install happened without errors and emcc is installed along with these links to the install in /opt/homebrew/bin/em*  which is in the path.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  36 Aug 22 20:04 em++ -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/em++
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  41 Aug 22 20:04 em-config -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/em-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  36 Aug 22 20:04 emar -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emar
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  41 Aug 22 20:04 embuilder -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/embuilder
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  36 Aug 22 20:04 emcc -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  39 Aug 22 20:04 emcmake -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emcmake
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  43 Aug 22 20:04 emconfigure -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emconfigure
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  38 Aug 22 20:04 emdump -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emdump
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  37 Aug 22 20:04 emdwp -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emdwp
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  38 Aug 22 20:04 emmake -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emmake
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  36 Aug 22 20:04 emnm -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emnm
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  41 Aug 22 20:04 emprofile -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emprofile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  40 Aug 22 20:04 emranlib -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emranlib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  37 Aug 22 20:04 emrun -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emrun
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  39 Aug 22 20:04 emscons -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emscons
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  38 Aug 22 20:04 emsize -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emsize
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  39 Aug 22 20:04 emstrip -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emstrip
lrwxr-xr-x  1 peterk  admin  44 Aug 22 20:04 emsymbolizer -> ../Cellar/emscripten/3.1.19/bin/emsymbolizer
```

So my old build scripts - more than 2 years old - use the way it was installed on an ubunto machine cloning the git repository and building things, which are are put in the home directory at ./emsdk and the build scripts Cmake and ruby files refer to what is in there, by an environment variable I set EMSDK="path to where it is".  It also downloads and compiles the "clibs" for C++ into that area as well.

The build files were based on having that location "EMSDK" installed or cloned from git with commands to use it, and having it writable to receive the downloaded libraries.

How do I use the newer one that is now installed with "brew install emscripten" ( and might also be installed with apt-get on ubuntu ? )

I haven't found any docs on this.

Comment: https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html ?

Comment: @connexo The whole getting started doc is based on installing an "emsdk" folder from a git repository. For some reason the "brew install emscripten" method and docs I have found do not provide that or an instruction of how to link to something that is that. My old build files were based on that "emsdk" being present. I was hoping the hombrew one which is also apparently the apple "official" app store way of installing it would be easier :) :) :) Haha !! –

Comment: Pardon - I was confused because of a more complicated situation installing it on Docker from source.

There really isn't anything to do on the mac as the items needed are put in the path by the install and one just runs the build with the path and it can find all the binaries :)